# Place files in download folder of iphone 7 simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, directory, simulator

I'm building an app that has to open the download  folder or , open all the .txt files on it and analyze the data contained inside every . txt. My question is, how can I place all the .txt files i want to retrieve in the download folder of the iphone simulator? In the real device, the files would get inside the phone via bluetooth from another device.

Im using Xcode 8.2.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a download folder in the sandbox of your application.
You can:

- save inside `temp` directory, but they will disappear in future probably after few days
- save inside the `cache` directory, but when the system is going to require more space they will be deleted
- save inside the `document` directory, or here create your `download` directory. In this case they will persist, but pay attention that if your files are big you should flag them to be not backed up during device backup.

In general you can use [`NSFileManager`](http://nshipster.com/nsfilemanager/) to create/remove files or directory.
Those directories are independent from the way you are getting the files, you can use them as you prefer.